# Error: The declared program id does not match the actual program id

Tags: anchor, node.js

I moved the app from devnet to mainnet. After building and deploying the app with anchor, received a new Program ID. I put this new Program ID in the source code in all the places needed.

I now try to call the app from the NodeJS API and I receive this error: **AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id.**

I then built again the same app but with the new Program ID provided and deployed it. During this operation, the deploy command returned another Program Id, which actually was the OLD Program ID that I had on Devnet.

I now try to use the Old and the New Program Ids as addresses in the NodeJS app, but still I received the same error in both cases.

Code Repo: https://github.com/The-Community-Atlas/solana-client-and-program

Comment: try running `anchor keys list` and seeing if the output is the address you expect for your program ID

Comment: By running that command i see the Old Key that i had when deployed in Devnet. Even if i put that key as the address in idl.json file for the Node.js app, i still get the same error.
here:
const idl = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./idl.json'));
const programId = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Not yet. How many times have you tried to deploy the Program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id.

This means that you need to check 2 things.

1. Check that `declare_id!` (usually in lib.rs) has the same key as the program keypair you are deploying with. You can get the pubkey of your program keypair by running `solana-keygen pubkey target/deploy/my_program-keypair.json`.
2. Check that the program keypair has 0 SOL! Programs cannot be deployed to if they have SOL. If you have accidentally transferred SOL to the program, then send it back to your wallet, and then try redeploying. You can check the SOL balance of your program with `solana balance $(solana-keygen pubkey target/deploy/my_program-keypair.json) --url mainnet-beta`.

Lastly, I recommend against using `anchor deploy` for versions before `0.27.0`, since it can be extremely difficult to debug for folks new to Solana. Instead, I recommend manually deploying your program & then manually deploying the IDL. There are also 2 steps for this.

1. Deploy your built program with: `solana deploy target/deploy/my_program.so ./target/deploy/my_program-keypair.json -k <path/to/your-wallet-keypair>.json --url mainnet-beta`
2. Deploy your anchor IDL with: `anchor idl init $(solana-keygen pubkey target/deploy/my_program-keypair.json) --filepath target/idl/my_program.json  --provider.cluster mainnet`

**Note** that `target/deploy` folder is created via `anchor build` or `cargo build-sbf` and you will lose your program's keypair if you ever run `cargo clean` or `anchor clean`, so always save `target/deploy/my_program-keypair.json` if you're planning on using it later.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to deploy the Program in Mainnet :)

Answer (score 2):

try running Solana Program deploy instead of anchor with the program id specified in --program-id flag

```
solana program deploy --program-id <PROGRAM_ID>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me `anchor clean` fix me problem!